Date picker input width with React Native Paper Dates
I want to add a DatePickerInput in my react native project using React Native Paper Dates.
It seems to work fine but I cannot adjust the width of the input.
              <DatePickerInput
                locale="en"
                label="Date de début"
                contentStyle={{ width: "200" }}
                value={inputDate}
                onChange={(d) => setInputDate(d)}
                inputMode="start"
              />

I must be missing something in the documentation because I tried adding style={{}} inline or even calling a styleSheet, I tried passing various props to the component, but none of that seems to be working.
